# How to fill some empty cell of a column with the previous row cell of the previous column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to fill some empty row cell of a column with the corresponding previous row cell. However i am not getting the right solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B':[6, 7, '', '', 10]}) 

df.replace('', np.nan) 

df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

The result is still empty. i would like to fill empty cell of column B with 3 and 4 from column A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.ffill` with `axis=1`:

```
In [2466]: df = df.replace('', np.nan).ffill(axis=1)

In [2451]: df
Out[2451]: 
   A     B
0  1   6.0
1  2   7.0
2  3   3.0
3  4   4.0
```

**OR:**

Use [`Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
In [2441]: df = df.replace('', np.nan)

In [2450]: df['B'] = df['B'].combine_first(df['A'])
```

OR use `Series.fillna`:

```
In [2441]: df = df.replace('', np.nan)

In [2457]: df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(df['A'])
```